# Reset elastix when acces the "unembedded freepbx" page

Tags: elastix

I run Elastix 2.5 on a "HP proliant ml3103 gen8 v2 " server.
when i want to access "unembedded freepbx" page on my elastix admin page, the Elastix WUI reset and i can't access the freePBX and Elatix pages.
I should re-login to my elastix WUI.

Answer (score 0):

I can't quite tell, but are you referring to attempting to access the unembedded FreePBX through the PBX tab of Elastix. Perhaps you're getting this message:

> **Unauthorized**
>
> You are not authorized to access this page. Enable direct access (Non-embedded) to FreePBX in "Security >> Advanced Security Settings" menu.

If so, the security switch to enable the "Unembedded FreePBX" is under System -> Advanced Settings. Once the switch is turned ON, the Unembedded FreePBX page becomes accessible.